# Change font size of the contents area in CKeditor

Tags: php, css, yii, ckeditor, stylesheet

I am using an extension in yii framework which is based on CKeditor (here is the [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/editme/))

I wanna change the size of the contents which is shown in CKeditor without applying in the output html code generated by the editor.

The editor creates an iframe and shows html contents inside it. When I try to write a css for its content it doesn't apply any changes.

I also used an script to change the css. it works fine when I write it in the console of my browser but not working on the script. here is my script:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    var cn = $('.cke').find('iframe').contents();
    cn.find('body').css('font-size','16px');
});
</script>
```

How can I write my own style to be applied on contents area only?

Comment: Please, show what have you tried so far? Using CSS works well for me.

Comment: I edited the question. Check it out please.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this with JS is [`CKEDITOR.addCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-addCss), which appends extra CSS to iframe's document `<head>`. Simply put it **before** the code which initialize editors (i.e. `CKEDITOR.replace`). It will apply to all the instances.

However, if I were you, I'd simply extend [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) and include some extra stylesheet(s).